# scheme error: Error: argument 1 of map has wrong type (NoneType)

Tags: scheme

I am taking cs61a course, and I typed exactly like the one the professor typed on the screen(link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GcZKmdzPWU&list=PL6BsET-8jgYXHupEH2vUfhlvwbJddZdJM&index=4) , I checked letter by letter,  but I keep getting error.

This is my scheme code:

```
(define (evenSub s)
  (if (null? s) nil
    (append (evenSub (cdr s))
      (map (lambda (t) (cons (car s) t))
        (if (even? (car s))
          (evenSub (cdr s))
          (oddSub (cdr s))
          )
        )
      (if (even? (car s)) (list (list (car s))) nil))))

(define (oddSub s)
  (if (null? s) nil
    (append (oddSub (cdr s))
      (map (lambda (t) (cons (car s) t))
        (if (odd? (car s))
          (evenSub (cdr s))
          (oddSub (cdr s))))
      (if (odd? (car s)) (list(list((car s))) nil)))))
```

and this is the error track information from the interpreter:

```
XL@mbp lab11 % python3 scheme -i evensub.scm
Welcome to the CS 61A Scheme Interpreter (version 1.2.5)

scm> (evenSub '(3 4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  0 (append (evensub (cdr s)) (map (lambda (t) (cons (car s) t)) (if (even? (car s)) (evensub (cdr s)) (oddsub (cdr s)))) (if (even? (car s)) (list (list (car s))) ()))
  1 (map (lambda (t) (cons (car s) t)) (if (even? (car s)) (evensub (cdr s)) (oddsub (cdr s))))
Error: argument 1 of map has wrong type (NoneType)
scm>
```

The problem lies in the last line, and this is the corrected version:

```
(if 
      (odd? (car s)) 
      (list (list (car s)))
      nil)))
      )
```

Comment: Look again at the last line of code as posted. (Don't "check letter by letter", think about how the Scheme system would evaluate `...(list ((car s)))...` )

Comment: Thank you very much! I corrected it to `(if (odd? (car s)) (list (list (car s)) nil)))))`, but I still get the error `argument 1 of map has wrong type (NoneType)`. Do you think anything else might be the problem?

Comment: Parentheses still not quite right on that last line. (That particular error message seems unhelpful - would recommend writing `if` forms as 3 lines, and using a command to fix indentation (if available) to make the sub-expressions of `if` clearer.)

Comment: @mnemenaut Thank you very much for helping me locate the error. I fixed it and added the corrected version to my question.  It is really difficult for me to debug the syntax error with scheme....